# Running TestNg suite multiple times

Tags: java, testng

I have say N number of test classes and I have one test suite say testing.xml which can run all those N tests , how to run testing.xml that is test suite multiple times ? Please help me out how to programatically run it multiple times

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="Suite1">
<test name="exampletest1">
<classes>
       <class name="tester.NewTest1" />
    </classes>
  </test>

  <test name="exampletest2">
    <classes>
       <class name="tester.NewTest2" />
    </classes>
  </test>

</suite>
```

Comment: I dont know how to do in xml but in the @Test annotation you can add invocationcount attribute to set your test multiple times. Hope this will halp you !

Comment: I am aware of invocationcount method !! Thing is I want to run all the tests 'N' number of times .. XML file actually is the test suite which has all the test classes to run

Comment: Please check this...http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng-programmatically

Comment: Thanks it worked , I used run method in loop !!

Comment: advanced version of this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50614115/how-does-one-record-test-history-with-testng

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here try this, you can modify this for whatever n times you want

```
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            List<String> suites = new ArrayList<String>();
            suites.add("testng.xml"); //path of .xml file to be run-provide complete path

            TestNG tng = new TestNG();
            tng.setTestSuites(suites);

            tng.run(); //run test suite
        }
```

Comment: Monk, can you please help me here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50614115/how-does-one-record-test-history-with-testng ?