# How to cycle through multiple classes multiple times with TestNG

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I am using Java/selenium and TestNG to create a test suite for a website. Every test case is a different class, but I would like to create an XML test ng file that will run through all 20 classes, say 10 times in order. Is this possible?

Comment: try using dataprovider for the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to run every test specific number of times with the same data you could use `invocationCount` property in your test classes, so if you want to run it 10 times you just use `@Test(invocationCount = 10)`.

If you need different sets of data for same test you should use testng [DataProvider](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders) and your tests will run 'n' times (where 'n' is number of data sets for your test).

Or you could run it programatically, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38432145/running-testng-suite-multiple-times) for more details.

Comment: I would use invocation count, however, each test requires that the previous one executes. For example, say the test suite has 5 test cases. Test case 1 has to execute before 2, which has to execute before 3, and so on. I would like the test suite to execute in the manner of: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. Invocationcount would do it like 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5.

Comment: Then see the link I posted and find how to run the whole xml programatically.

Comment: Define the test suites in the XML, including any test classes or methods you see fit, per the TestNG documentation. You can define test dependencies in the XML or the `@Test` annotation, per the TestNG documentation. You can use data providers to run different data through the tests, per the TestNG documentation. You can do all this programmatically as stated in this answer, per the TestNG documentation.

Comment: @acikojevic - how do I run an entire class 10 times? Is there a class level annotation for that or do I have to set invocationCount for every method ?